# X-editable select based on data-attribute

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, x-editable

I have following code which is for setting select options. Is it possible to somehow add country filter based on a data-attribute? So if I had `data-country = 'DE'` the query would be `SELECT * FROM vats WHERE country = 'DE' ORDER BY name`

```
$('.editable.vatcode').editable({
    source: [
        <?php
            $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM vats ORDER BY name");
            $i = 1;
            while ($option = $sql->fetch()) {
                echo "{value: '".$option['code']."', text: '".$option['name']."'}";
                if ($i < $sql->rowCount()) {
                    echo ", ";
                }
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
    ]
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some html for that too

Answer (score 0):

//you need to put the result in array and json_encode echo , it's work with me.

```
$('.editable.vatcode').editable({
    source: [

    <?php
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM vats ORDER BY name");
        while ($option = $sql->fetch()) {
      result[]=array('value': $option['code'], 'text': $option['name']);}  echo json_encode($result);              
    ?>
]});
```